# База данных. C# Winforms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Здравствуйте.Я создаю приложения для учет расходов. Я создал базу и соединил с формой. Но данные из базы данных не показывает. Помогите пожалуйста в чём моя ошибка.

Вот исходный код:

```
namespace winformtest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void выходToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
            if (sqlConnection != null && sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlConnection.Close();
        }

        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\odmen\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\winformtest\winformtest\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

            SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Expense]", sqlConnection);

            try
            {
                sqlReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                while (await sqlReader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Id"]) + "  " + Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Sum"]) + "  " + Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Data"]) + "  " + Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Type"]));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), ex.Source.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sqlReader != null)
                    sqlReader.Close();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sqlConnection != null && sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

А вот ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь у меня не работает команда INSERT. Не добавляется.
Вот исходный код:
 private void  buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (label9.Visible)
                label9.Visible = false;

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxSum1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxSum1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxData1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxData1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxType1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxType1.Text))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Expense] (Sum, Data, Type) VALUES(@Sum, @Data, @Type)", sqlConnection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Sum", textBoxSum1.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Data", textBoxData1.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Type", textBoxType1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            label9.Visible = true;
            label9.Text = "Поля 'Cумма' , 'Дата' и 'Категории' должны быть заполнены!";
        }
    }

    private  async void обновитьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Expense]", sqlConnection);

        try
        {
            sqlReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

            while (await sqlReader.ReadAsync())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Id"]) + "    " + Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Sum"]) + "    " + Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Data"]) + "    " + Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Type"]));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), ex.Source.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlReader != null)
                sqlReader.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело действительно в пробелах. Если в пути содержатся пробелы (`Visual Studio 2015`), то строку нужно заключить в кавычки. Ну и убираем пробел после буквы диска.

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\odmen\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\winformtest\winformtest\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True";
```

Comment: Огромное  спасибо вам.Работает)))

Answer (score 2):

В строке подключения пробел:
AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\odmen\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\winformtest\winformtest\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

Я подозреваю, что дело в нем. Удали и все должно заработать.

Comment: не работает все равно.Что именно надо удалить?